# MySQL server has gone away when writing 73 elements or more

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, timeout

I'm using PDO and MySQL.

Basically, every time I try to insert/update 73 elements or more, i get a "MySQL server has gone away" error. It happens over various different scripts doing very different things.

Here is an example of the code I use

```
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.hostinger.fr;dbname=XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$prepare = 'UPDATE table SET field = ? WHERE id = ?';
$update = $bbd->prepare($prepare);
foreach ($elements as $el){
    $update->execute(array($el['value'], $el['id']));
    echo 'error code : <br />';
    var_dump($update->errorCode());
    echo '<br />error info : <br />';
    var_dump($update->errorInfo());
}
```

If $elements has more that 73 elements, the database isn't updated, and I get the following for each $el :

```
error code :
string(5) "HY000"
error info :
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "HY000" [1]=> int(2006) [2]=> string(26) "MySQL server has gone away" }
```

Based on my tests, it's only the number of elements modified that create the error. (And not things such as : the length of the query, the size of the elements I'm updating, the number of fields I'm updating for each element). Also, it might be worth noting that it doesn't matter if it is 73+ queries updating 1 element each (such as the code above), or one query updating 73+ elements : the error pops either way.

I get that the problem is probably because the server timed out, but 72 elements modified seem very small. I opened a ticket for my hosting company and I'm waiting for a response, but maybe someone here might help too with any hindsight.

Thanks in advance.

NB : I tried putting the following before connecting to the database, but it did nothing :

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

---

**Additional info :** when using phpMyAdmin, there is no problem, even for requests bigger than 73 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control over the MySQL server, you should try to change my.cnf file and restart it then.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

Comment: As far as I know, I don't have control over the MySQL server. My host is Hostinger (premium plan).

Comment: I added the fact that everything works fine if I use phpMyAdmin

Comment: As far as I can see from the other places I Googled, this is "a standard / well-known problem" with Hostinger... You can try to play with transactions `$dbh->beginTransaction();` before the loop and `$dbh->commit();` in the loop.
I guess the support response will be something "limit number of requests to the DB" or "optimize your requests".